# On the screen appears SSD locked and Enter user password: I never entered any password

Tags: ssd, bios, passwords, ata

[image]I have an Acer Veriton desktop PC running Windows 11 Pro.

One day I turn on the PC and suddenly it appears:

> "SSD Locked"

And then:

> "Enter User Password"

Windows won't start.

I never entered a password, neither on BIOS nor Windows.

Victoria software says:

> "SSD locked by ATA PASSWORD"

I would like to at least be able to see what files and folders are on the SSD. If I can then also save the data, even better.

My SSD is: MyMedia 2.5" Sata III 7mm 256 GB.

I reset the BIOS by both removing the CR2032 battery and moving the CMOD jumper; all to no avail.

No one has used the pc besides me

I am sure I have not enabled local encryption of the ssd in the bios.

I clicked the Unlock button on the Victoria software but nothing changes (you have to enter the password which I don't know )

Comment: Without the password you won’t be able to access the data as more than likely the device was encrypted. Modern devices passwords cannot be just reset by pulling their CMOS battery.

Comment: The ATA password is built in to the drive, not the motherboard firmware. Resetting motherboard setting will not do anything to the drive. Has someone else that could have set a password recently used this computer?

Comment: Most SSD's allow local encryption. This setting is disabled by default, but can be enabled through the BIOS. To decrypt it, you do need to know the password. Maybe you accidentally enabled it in the BIOS and the password is the same as your bios or windows user?

Comment: In Victoria software, what does the "Unlock" option from the main menu?

Answer (score 0):

If the Victoria software "Unlock" option from the main menu
doesn't work, here is some more
[advice](https://www.acerrepairblog.us/aspire-5740-5740d-5340/remove-hdd-password.html).
Unfortunately, you'll need the help of Acer Support.

> To remove the hard disk security password on an Acer laptop, you can
> follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start by turning off your Acer laptop completely and disconnecting any power source.
> 2. Locate the small cover on the bottom of the laptop that protects the hard drive bay. Depending on your specific Acer model, this cover
>    may have a small lock symbol on it.
> 3. Once you find the hard drive bay cover, remove any screws that are holding it in place. Then, carefully remove the cover by sliding it
>    off or lifting it up, depending on the installation method of your
>    laptop model.
> 4. After removing the cover, you will see the hard drive inside the bay. On the hard drive, there should be a small label or sticker with
>    a 5 to 8-digit code. This code is the current hard disk security
>    password.
> 5. With the code in hand, go to the Acer support website or contact Acer customer support directly. Provide them with the serial number of
>    your laptop and the hard disk security code. They will help provide
>    you with a master password based on this information.
> 6. Once you receive the master password from Acer, power on your laptop and enter the hard drive security password. This time, use the
>    master password provided by Acer. If successful, it should unlock the
>    hard drive and allow you to access your data.   Note: If you are
>    unable to get a master password from Acer, you may need to replace the
>    hard drive entirely. Keep in mind that this will result in data loss
>    unless you have a backup.